# Deleting an answer?

Tags: support

I answered a question with an answer that provided with current reasearch at the time seemed correct and wise. However further reasearch into the subject proved my original thoughts incorrect, and now I wish to have this answer deleted.

So, how many votes does it take to delete my answer. Also, do I get my reputation points returned since the answer was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this works as just about any other stack exchange site, you can delete your answer by clicking the `delete` button under it **unless** it's an accepted answer, in which case you should flag it for moderator attention

Comment: How many votes does it take to delete?

Comment: @Nick Only one if you're the poster

Comment: Oh ok, it confused me when it said voted to delete instead of saying deleted.

Comment: @Nick - Certian users with enough rep can vote to delete questions/answers.  This takes 3 votes.  The OP's vote only takes one.