# To delete an answer question

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers

I'd like to delete [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/the-pros-and-cons-of-democratic-socialism-in-america-today) which has been put on hold too broad (see below). I keep getting the below message when I apply the deletion.

[image]

[image]w

### Question

Other than asking the person that answered to delete there answer and flagging with relevant notes and questions for moderators, is there anything further to do to have it deleted entirely?

### Posts I reviewed already

- [**Deleting an Answer**](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/deleting-an-answer)